# button and sliding menu

Tags: html, css, menu, css-animations

Why doesn't the input tag inside a label tag work while input tag outside of a label tag work unless there is a workaround?

This cause the  to slide to the left as the input tag is outside of the label tag.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger"/>
<label id="menuButton" for="nav-trigger"></label>
```

While this doesn't cause the div to slide to the left as the input tag is inside the label tag, however I added a checkbox to make sure it is working but no luck.

```
<label id="menuButton" for="nav-trigger">
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger"/>
</label>
```

Jsfiddle (input outside label tag works): https://jsfiddle.net/dxs6040/4ovp3zty/3/

Jsfiddle (input inside label tag does not works): https://jsfiddle.net/dxs6040/hbtho680/6/

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because your css. If you are targeting input element like this .nav-trigger:checked + label, the next first label element that comes after checkbox being checked. If you change the order in HTML this is not valid anymore.